# How can I enable iAd when using Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios7, iad, sprite-kit

In IOS 7, we can enable iAd very easy when using:

> self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;

in code **ViewDidLoad** of UIViewController

However, I cannot use this in my ViewController (the ViewControl that load SKScene). My game is crash when loading.

So how can I active iAd in my game (using Sprite Kit)?

Comment: I need my game in **Landscape** so I add this in: **- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews** but it will be crashed.However, if i give it in **viewDidLoad**, this game will be **portrait**. When I can add this code **self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;** to enable iAD?

Comment: http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only show iAd in a UIViewController subclass. You are doing it right. Put the following code in your UIViewController and not in the SKScene.

Please refer to this tutorial for the exact code: http://tutorials.veasoftware.com/2013/10/10/how-to-add-iads/

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e57680' This is make some error when I do this. Do you try it in your game?

Comment: Where do you have your iAd code? In the UIViewController or in the SKScene?

Comment: in **- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews** because I need my game landscape.

Comment: Please add your whole code so I can see better what's the problem.

Comment: **- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews**
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        SKScene * scene = [LKMenuScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        
        [skView presentScene:scene];
        **self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;**
    }
} I write this code in viewWillLayoutSubview because I need my game landscape

Comment: You only have that line of code for display the iAd? I don't think it is only that line...check out some tutorials online that explains the code you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. iAd still work when you add only this code **self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES; **. I just want to know how to add this iAd with landscape Sprite Kit game.

Comment: So you got your problem fixed?

Comment: I added a banner like your tutorial but it still use the width of portrait (768 pixel) so it is not full of screen.

Comment: Add this: banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are accessing the view property. When using iAds you need to replace .view with .originalContentView. For example:

```
SKView* skView = (SKView *)self.view;
```

is replaced with

```
SKView* skView = (SKView *)self.originalContentView;
```